# Dynamic GridLayout with evenly spaced controls

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

We need to place arbitrary controls in a Grid, supporting colspan (and probably further down the road rowspan, too). So I was looking at [Android's GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), as it seems to just support that. I've set up a minimal example just placing TextViews in some cells.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/root">
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:text="Erstes" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_columnSpan="2" android:layout_columnWeight="1"  android:background="#333333" />
        <TextView android:text="Zweites" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="2" android:layout_columnWeight="1"  android:background="#666666" />
        <TextView android:text="Drittes" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="1" android:layout_columnWeight="1"  android:background="#888888"/>
        <TextView android:text="Viertes" android:layout_row="2" android:layout_column="3" android:layout_columnWeight="1"  android:background="#aaaaaa" />
        <Space android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_width="10dp" android:layout_columnWeight="1" android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Had to put in the `Space` with a fixed width in there to not have the first cell in the second row collapse. My first question would be, if there is another way to do this? As I would like to avoid setting the width of anything as the number of columns and corresponding site of each cell isn't really known beforehand. (Edit: I guess you can disregard the `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` part of that. That was just me trying around.)

Also with that XML (or by doing the same in code) I end up with unevenly spaced columns in the final result. It appears that columns containing cells with wider content (text) in them are given more space overall. How can I avoid this?

You can see the result on the picture below, although it might be barely noticeable at first glance. Best noticeable for the cell only containing the 10dp-wide `Space` view.
[image]

Am I expecting too much of GridLayout here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just noticed that you're referencing the platform GridLayout which I think doesn't support weight.

Comment: It does, since API Level 21.

Comment: Regarding the cells with content looking wider, you might want to add `android:layout_width="0dp"`. This is because I think the layouts default to `wrap_content` for their width.

Edit: Just tried it that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the obvious answer might be to add `Space` view wherever the controls are missing and set all the views to have equal weight.

And for the second issue, it would be good to set the `layout_width` to 0dp as they're set to wrap_content by default.

Ignore the following as you're already using API 21.

The Support Library has a better [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html). It lets you specify weights for each view, which means you can evenly distribute space by letting each of them have equal weight.

To be more specific, add `compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${SUPPORT_LIBRARY}"` to your list of Gradle dependencies, where ${SUPPORT_LIBRARY} is the latest version available.

And use `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` tag for the layout.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually used that one when doing this in code. Changed it in XML to use the regular GridLayout for comparison. As I'm testing on a Marshmallow device though, I have the same support for weights with the regular one as with the Support one. But thanks anyways!

Comment: You are my personal hero! Setting `layout_width` to 0dp did the trick! I was aware of the default, but not of the implications. Many many thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Happy to hear it worked for you.